# Flutter: Merging 2 InheritedWidget as parent for MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, inherited-widget

Can a child widget (`MaterialApp`) inherit from 2 separate inherited widgets? Like I need one inherited widget for translation (`LocalizationProvider`) and another for navigation (`AppStateProvider`). They work fine separately but unable to make them work together... :(

```
// 1st one
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LocalizationProvider(
        state: LocalizationProvider.of(context).state,
        child: FlavorBanner(
          child: MaterialApp(
              // Other code
          ),
        ),
   );
  }


// 2nd one
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppStateProvider(
           state: this,
             child: FlavorBanner(
               child: MaterialApp(
                      // Other code
               ),
             ),
        );
    }
```